# VMWare VMs not autostarting after reboot

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

I have an issue where my VMs do not auto-start after an ESXi reboot. They are all properly configured to auto-start, but after rebooting the ESXi they are still off -- I have to manually go and hit play to start them.

More details:
-ESXi 4.1 server is patched with Update 3 (build 800380)
-VM is running the latest version of the vmware tools (8.3.1.7 build 784891)
-VM is set to automatic startup (only 1 vm on server) with a 30 second delay

When the ESXi host is rebooted, the VM does not ever auto start.  I got a copy of the log files from the host but I am not quite sure where to look to find out if/why the Vms not starting. Any ideas?

Comment: Did this ever work? There was a period where autostart was broken on ESXi 5.0...

Comment: Is this server part of an HA cluster?

Comment: How long are you waiting for them to autostart?

Comment: Are the VMs on external storage (SAN or similar)?